# errors ServerXMLHTTP.send in classic ASP when I am using iis7.5

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, iis-7.5, serverxmlhttp

I have shared hosting which runs iis7.5 .

I wanted to run this code which allows me to display the content of the another url.

```
<%                
                                      
url = "abc.com"
                        
Response.Write(url)
                        
set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP") 
xmlhttp.open "GET", url, false 
xmlhttp.send "" 
Response.write xmlhttp.responseText 
set xmlhttp = nothing 

%>
```

This code was running perfectly on IIS6, but when I migrate to IIS7 it was giving me error of `operation timed out` on ' xmlhttp.send ""  ' line. It means its unable to establish connection.

Do I need to do some changes in web.config to run this code or Is there any alternative code.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue. It seems `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP` is having problems connecting to it's own site.
I solved this problem by creating a new "site" with the same directory but with a different port. When I call `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP` with the different port `HTTP://SERVER:PORT/same/path/to/script.asp` it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the fact that you're missing the `http://` from the url that script works just fine on one of our Windows 2008R2/IIS7.5 servers.

I would check to see if your hoster has blocked outbound port 80 connections either on the server (Windows Firewall or IPSec), or within their shared hosting LAN.

Comment: @vikrant As I said in my answer, check to see if your hoster has blocked outbound port 80 connections either on the server (Windows Firewall or IPSec), or within their shared hosting LAN.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP.6.0 or MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP.4.0 depends the version of MSXL installed in your system.